# Sending and validating Lambda code to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Lambda node.js function like so:

```
function storeUser(email, username, password, salt, fn) {
    // Bytesize
    var len = 128;
    crypto.randomBytes(len, function(err, token) {
        if (err) return fn(err);
        token = token.toString('hex');
        dynamodb.putItem({
            TableName: "Users",
            Item: {
                email: {
                    S: email
                },
                username: {
                    S: username
                },
                passwordHash: {
                    S: password
                },
                passwordSalt: {
                    S: salt
                },
                verified: {
                    BOOL: false
                },
                verifyToken: {
                    S: token
                }
            },
            ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists (email)'
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return fn(err);
            else fn(null, token);
        });
    });
}
```

The event handler is like so:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var email = event.email;
    var username = event.username;
    var clearPassword = event.password;

    computeHash(clearPassword, function(err, salt, hash) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail('Error in hash: ' + err);
        } else {
            storeUser(email, username, hash, salt, function(err, token) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.code == 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
                        // userId already found
                        context.succeed({
                            created: false
                        });
                    } else {
                        context.fail('Error in storeUser: ' + err);
                    }
                } else {
                    context.succeed({
                        created: true
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I want to make the username and email unique. How do I ensure that in the write to the db and if one (or both) is not unique, get an error back saying which is not unique?

Comment: Your question's title makes no sense. Looking at your code, you are already using ConditionExpression to enforce unique email addresses, just do the same thing for the other property you want to enforce uniqueness on.

Comment: read the last line: I want to know which is NOT unique (get an error back saying which is not unique?)

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and dirty way to do it. It's not extraordinarily efficient but it gets the job done:

```
const // You want const because no required packages ever change at runtime
    AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // QUERY USERNAME FIRST
    var table = 'tableName';
    var paramsUNCheck = {
        TableName : table,
        ProjectionExpression : 'hash',
        KeyConditionExpression : 'hash = :v_hash AND range = :v_rng',
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
            ':v_hash' : { S : 'hash' },
            ':v_rng'  : { S : event.username }
        }
    }
    
    ddb.query (paramsUNCheck, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail (JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
        } else {
            if (data.Count === 0) {
                var paramsEMCheck = {
                    TableName : table,
                    ProjectionExpression : 'hash',
                    KeyConditionExpression : 'hash = :v_hash',
                    FilterExpression : 'email = :v_eml',
                    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
                        ':v_hash' : { S : 'hash' },
                        ':v_eml' : { S : event.email }
                    }
                }
                ddb.query (paramsEMCheck, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        context.fail (JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
                    } else {
                        if (data.Count === 0) {
                            // REGISTER IF IT PASSES ALL CHECKS
                            var paramsReg = {
                                TableName : table,
                                Item : {
                                    'hash' : { S : 'hash' },
                                    'username' : { S : event.username },
                                    'password' : { S : event.password },
                                    'email'    : { S : event.email }
                                }
                            }
                            ddb.putItem (paramsReg, function (err, data) {
                                if (err) context.fail (JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                                else
                                    context.succeed ({ done: 'yes' });
                            });
                        } else {
                            context.succeed ('Email already used, please try again.')
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                context.succeed ('Username taken, please try again.')
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Now, the reason why I say this is a dirty way of doing it is because you do *two* queries.

With that said, running ***reads*** is significantly cheaper than running ***writes***. The reason for this madness:

> One read capacity unit = one strongly consistent read per second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for items up 4 KB in size.
>
> One write capacity unit = one write per second, for items up to 1 KB in size.
>
> - [From here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)

Basically, it's way cheaper to run two read requests then one write request. PER PROVISIONAL THROUGHPUT the cost is ~$0.09/ read throughput and ~$0.48/ write throughput.

But wait, don't you have to do a write anyway? Well, yes you do, but it's a write that *should* **always** succeed. What if you have a user constantly hitting that lambda? You'll want a read on the front line of defense and not a write. Basically I'm as cheap as possible. I'll crank read throughput all day long if it means not 'uping' the write (within reason).

**The other way to do it** is [Conditional Writes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) and you're going to want to check `begins_with usernameofemail@gmail.com` all the way up to the end - basically forcing a full string check, so disregard the "begins with".

Comment: what is the hash? the v_hash

Comment: @cdub, yup. The :v is value

Comment: I have to look at how the hash value and ranges work as a composite key